# Testing request with cookie

Tags: go

I wrote a cookie getter and setter. Now I want to test it, and wrote following test function.

```
func TestAuthorizationReader(t *testing.T) {

    tw := httptest.NewServer(testWriter())
    tr := httptest.NewServer(Use(testReader()))
    defer tw.Close()
    defer tr.Close()

    c := &http.Client{}
    rs, err := c.Get(tw.URL)
    assert.NoError(t, err, "Should not contain any error")

    // Assign cookie to client
    url, err := rs.Location()
    fmt.Print(url)
    assert.NoError(t, err, "Should not contain any error")
    //c.Jar.SetCookies(url, rs.Cookies())

}
```

The test fail at the second part, as output message I've got

```
- FAIL: TestAuthorizationReader (0.05s)
 Location:       logged_test.go:64
 Error:          No error is expected but got http: no Location header in response
 Messages:       Should not contain any error
```

I can not get the URL location pointer, what do I wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Response.Location` method returns the value of the `Location` response header.  You would usually only expect to see this header for redirect responses, so it isn't surprising you got this error.

If you want to know the URL used to retrieve a particular response, try `rs.Request.URL.String()`.  Even if the HTTP library followed a redirect to retrieve the document, this will look at the request used for this particular response, which is what you'd be after when determining a cookie's origin.

---

If you just want the client to keep track of cookies set by requests it processes though, all you should need to do is set the `Jar` attribute on your client.  Something like this:

```
import "net/http/cookiejar"

...
c := &http.Client{
    Jar: cookiejar.New(nil),
}
```

Now cookies set in earlier responses should be set in future requests to the same origin.

Comment: How can I do a request with cookie then?

Comment: If you set the `Jar` attribute on the client (using the implementation from `net/http/cookiejar`), the client should automatically handle `Set-Cookie` response headers, and add appropriate `Cookie` request headers.

Comment: @zero_coding Request and Response do contain methods to set and read cookies. If you use a Client with a RoundTripper which doesn't follow redirect you can check add and check cookies very easily. Stuffing them into a Jar as James suggested is the best if you do not want to mess with the cookies yourself.